# is there any api for get substrate api client verison?

Tags: polkadot, api, chainspec, blockchain, sidecar

all.
Currently sidecar owns a api "/node/version" for get polkadot node version.
But is there any api could return sidecar api version for us?

Answer (score 2):

How are you running sidecar? If you have it installed in your project you can query the version using the CLI:

```
node_modules/.bin/substrate-api-sidecar --version
```

If you have installed it globally:

```
substrate-api-sidecar --version
```

And if you are query through the docs page: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/

You can see in the top the version 14.2.2
[image]